# R dataframe converting data types?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and trying to find my feet.

I have an issue with an R dataframe where it seems to be automatically converting my data types. 
Take the below code, which is used to create the dataframe.

```
name <- c("Amy", "Bill", "Carl")
class(name)

DAD <- c(80, 65, 50)
BDA <- c(70, 50, 80.4)

gender <- as.factor(c("F", "M", "M"))
nationality <- as.factor(c("IRL", "UK", "IRL"))
age <- c(20, 21, 22)

age <- as.integer(age)
DAD <- as.integer(DAD)
BDA <- as.integer(BDA)

student <- data.frame(name, age, gender, nationality, DAD, BDA)

student$average <- as.double(student$BDA + student$DAD)/2
```

When I run str(student) after this, I get the below screenshot: 
[image]

When I add the below entries, it appears that all of my data types are converting to chars - why?

```
student <- rbind(student, c("Dennis", 23, "M", "UK", 55, 70))
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Because a `vector` cannot have multiple datatypes.  It will coerce to a single data type based on the order of preference of data types.  Here, `character` is above that of `numeric` in preference and thus if there is a single `character`, the whole vector gets converted.  Remedy - use a `list`

```
student <- rbind(student, list("Dennis", 23, "M", "UK", 55, 70, NA))
```